# Grep files with uncommented "console.log" string

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I need to return all files in a directory which contain the string `console.log` uncommented.  So I think I should search for any line which does not have the string `//` between the newline and the `console.log` string.

This command returns both commented and uncommented console.log.  I want to exclude instances where console.log is commented.

```
grep -H -r  "^.*[^//].*console\.log" /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com
```

The command I need would match these lines:

```
var num = 0;  console.log(num);
alert('some text'); console.log('anything');
  console.log();
```

but not match these lines:

```
var num = 0; // console.log(num);
//alert('some text'); console.log('anything');
  // console.log();
```

Comment: What about multiline comment using `/* console.log('foo'); */` ?

Comment: Yes, my solution will have false positives for multiline comments.  But I use console.log almost exclusively with single line comment.

Comment: @anubhava Even if it is nearly 8 years ago that you asked, maybe this is still relevant for you, so have a look at my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17147807/887930

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Use `-L` switch</strike>

```
grep -rL '//.*console\.log' directory
```

#### Update:

```
grep -rlP '^(?!.*//.*console\.log)(?=.*console\.log)' directory
```

Comment: This lists files without a commented `console.log` string, which is not the same as files with a `console.log` string not preceded by a `//` in the same line.  This answer matches almost every file, including files meeting the criteria I need.

Comment: @steampowered - My mistake. I have updated answer with correct solution.

Comment: This seems to be working.  I'll check more thoroughly and mark it correct if there are no holes.  Thanks!  I thought the solution might need lookarounds.

Comment: Thanks, i'm using the regexp 
^(?!.*//.*console\.log)(?=.*console\.log)
in vscode instead of grep.

Answer (score 1):

Extending Ωmega's answer: In order to find mulitline comments (`/* console.log(); */`) additionally use:

```
^(?!.*//.*console\.log)^(?!.*/\*.*console\.log)(?=.*console\.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to list all files **containing uncommented console.log**:

```
grep -rlL "\/\/.*console\.log" /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com
```

Comment: This matches almost every file, including the criteria I need.  Thank you for attempting though.  @Ωmega also answered this way at first before using lookarounds to give the correct answer.

Comment: No problem. He was 3 minutes faster than me, but including his "edit" he was 30 minutes after me ;)
But the most important is that you got the solution!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use invert matching using the `-v` switch in `grep`.

```
grep -H -r "console\.log" /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com | grep -v "//"
```